# How do you uninstall old custom installs of Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, uninstallation, beta

When I install a beta, I do a custom install into a separate folder to the latest release version. I have several old beta installs.

How do I uninstall the old custom versions of Xcode?

Can I just trash the folder?
Our do I need to use Terminal?

The release notes suggest to use this:

> $ sudo
>   /Library/uninstall-devtools
>   --mode=all

But will this just uninstall my original official release version 3.2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the release notes:

*Throughout this document `<Xcode>` refers to the path in which the Developer Tools 
Essentials components are installed.*

...

*To uninstall iPhone SDK and Xcode developer tools on the boot volume along with the 
`<Xcode>` directory, from a Terminal window type:*

```
$ sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

So, if you used the default installation path of `/Developer`, you can uninstall using this command:

```
$ sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Comment: The OP is asking about uninstalling only one of the Xcode installs. uninstall-devtools will uninstall all of the installs, including the official release. Since there can only be 1 version of the Developer Tools Essentials components installed at a time, there is no way to use that terminal command to just remove a particular xcode install.

Comment: @Harkonian `uninstall-devtools` does _not_ uninstall _all_ installations, it uninstalls only "its" installation, i.e. from a single `<Xcode>` directory. There can be multiple versions of the Developer Tools Essentials installed at once (you just have to use a path other than `/Developer` for the subsequent installations). That's what the OP is asking about. He installed in `/SomeOtherDir` and he wants to uninstall _that_ installation. The way to do it is to use `sudo /SomeOtherDir/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`.

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple Developer folders, you can drag any of them to the trash without damaging the others.  Developer folders are completely standalone.

Installing Developer Tools from the download image can also install tools in /usr for Unix-style and makefile-based development.  The uninstall-devtools script removes these as well. That, also, should not affect remaining Developer folders.

Comment: +1 Thanks. This is good to know. It was not clear to be previously why I couldn't just trash my developer folder to uninstall extra copies of Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but I have no rep- so to further clarify Jon-Eric's answer:

...from a Terminal window type:

```
$ sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Enter this exactly (from the root of your volume), do not cd into the directory and try it:

```
$ cd /XCode4/Library
$ sudo uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

This will not work. Just a FYI, this caught me up...

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, my system had archived xcode 3 even though I was only using 4, and it placed it in /Developer-old, so running

`sudo /Developer-old/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`

removed the older xcode that had stuck around.